# "dojo is not defined" - Firefox 3.5 issue?

Tags: firefox, dojo

Please take a look at this code:
http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testAjaxDojo
Just tab off the "domain" input field to try to make the Ajax run. 
(Note: the test Ajax web service always sends back the same message, it pretends to check if domain is available but it really doesn't).

When running in Firefox 3.5, I get "dojo not defined" on the dojo.xhrGet statement. 
It works fine in IE7 and Chrome browsers, and one friend tested on Firefox 3.0 and it worked.

1) Is there something wrong with Firefox 3.5 not properly getting the dojo javascript from the CDN?  Possibly a caching issue?

2) Do you Dojo gurus know of this problem?  Is it something that has already been reported to Firefox?

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Update: 9/1/ afternoon - I have uninstalled and re-installed Firefox 3.5.2 (but I kept my profile settings), and got same problem.  I'm on Windows Vista Ultimate.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 3.5 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem.  It was the add-on called "No-Script".  Even though I had set No-Script to allow scripts globally, something in that tool was causing the issue.  I upgraded to new version of No-Script and still had problem.  If I disable the add-on (from the Tools/Add-ons screen), then Dojo loads perfectly from the CDN and life is good again.

I probably lost 6-8 hours on this stupid issue. Hope this posts saves someone else the time. Please "vote-up" the answer if it does.

Comment: See this thread on NoScript forum for my follow-up there. 
http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2498&p=10356#p10356

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, on Firefox 3.5 (mac) works fine. Try to do the following on your Firefox browser, insert the dojo library url in the url bar:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js
```

Usually it helps to solve any cache problems and forces Firefox to fetch the file.

If it still doesn't work, just store dojo in your server and use it locally.

Comment: I pasted the URL, and I can view the JavaScript source in the browser.  But I go back and refresh the trouble page - and it still has error.  I'm using Google App Engine which has a limit of 3000 files upload.  If the CDN works, I want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine here with NoScript enabled.
I just needed to allow both "3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com" and "ajax.googleapis.com".